# android spinner not getting value

Tags: java, android

I've been trying to figure this out, but each example I find online is totally misguiding me (could be because am really new to android). I simply want to get the value of selected item from spinner. I did the following:

```
public class AddDiscountActivity extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener{
```

then inside this main class I defined a string shopCategory. Then I implemented this method inside the class:

```
@Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        shopCategory = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    }
```

Nevertheless, I still get the value empty because in my database, all fields are showing except category. Ay recommendations?

Comment: I guess you override toString() method and return empty.

Comment: show your container type ..how to save your data.??show more code..